# How to change precedence of logical OR in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery selector:

```
div div ul li.normal a, div div ul li.massive a
```

Is there a logically equivalent selector like this:

```
div div ul (li.normal, li.massive) a
```

Any better solution than:

```
$('div div ul li').filter('.normal, .massive').find('a')
```

Comment: Not aware of anything like that. Another way is a filter. `$('div div ul a').filter('li.normal, li.massive')`

Comment: @mrtsherman. Doesn't work. `filter` only operate on current set of elements.

Comment: You are right, jmort253 was nice enough to post the correct way to use filter in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really personal preference, and involves details about what you think may change in your application over time. If I expect the two selectors to diverge in the future, I may keep them completely separate using a comma, like so:

```
$('div div ul li.normal a, div div ul li.massive a')
```

However, if there isn't any plan to change the structure, your example in the question would work great.

If you're ever in doubt about the speed of a selector, you could put some timing code around it and compare which selector is faster.

The [Multiple Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/) is basically the jQuery selector equivalent of an OR. In the documentation it says:

> Selects the combined results of all the specified selectors.

It can be used in any combination of element selectors, class selectors, id selectors, attribute selectors, etc.

Thus, if you wanted to adhere 100% to the DRY principle, your example appears to be the most simplified version:

```
// -----------------------[ normal || .massive ]--------
$('div div ul li').filter('.normal, .massive').find('a')
```

Comment: I just feel bad for not following the `DRY` principle.

Comment: It's a design decision, and DRY is a general guideline for when in doubt. I work closely with a designer who changes things a lot, and we find that our changes work well together when we carve out some room for divergence in the HTML structure. In general, I like your solution from your question and believe that will work just fine.